# Remove newlines from xml input with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, line

For one input xml with newlines in tags the output of parsing the stylesheet xsl include the newline of origin. 
I need to remove the newlines in the output to get a field semicolon separated output. 
xml input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONSOLIDATED_LIST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://test/test.xsd" dateGenerated="2012-08-08T19:03:43.593-04:00">
    <INDIVIDUALS>
        <INDIVIDUAL><DATAID>5</DATAID><VERSIONNUM>1</VERSIONNUM><FIRST_NAME> TEST </FIRST_NAME><SECOND_NAME>TEST1</SECOND_NAME><THIRD_NAME/><UN_LIST_TYPE></UN_LIST_TYPE><REFERENCE_NUMBER></REFERENCE_NUMBER><LISTED_ON>2016-11-30</LISTED_ON><COMMENTS1></COMMENTS1><DESIGNATION><VALUE></VALUE></DESIGNATION><NATIONALITY><VALUE></VALUE></NATIONALITY><LIST_TYPE><VALUE></VALUE></LIST_TYPE><LAST_DAY_UPDATED><VALUE/></LAST_DAY_UPDATED><INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS><QUALITY/><ALIAS_NAME/></INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS><INDIVIDUAL_ADDRESS><COUNTRY/></INDIVIDUAL_ADDRESS><INDIVIDUAL_DATE_OF_BIRTH><TYPE_OF_DATE>EXACT</TYPE_OF_DATE><DATE>1964-07-17</DATE></INDIVIDUAL_DATE_OF_BIRTH><INDIVIDUAL_PLACE_OF_BIRTH/><INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT><TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT></TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT><NUMBER></NUMBER></INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT><SORT_KEY/><SORT_KEY_LAST_MOD/></INDIVIDUAL>
        <INDIVIDUAL><DATAID></DATAID><VERSIONNUM></VERSIONNUM><FIRST_NAME>TEST</FIRST_NAME><SECOND_NAME>TEST2</SECOND_NAME><THIRD_NAME/><UN_LIST_TYPE></UN_LIST_TYPE><REFERENCE_NUMBER></REFERENCE_NUMBER><LISTED_ON>2016-11-30</LISTED_ON><COMMENTS1/><DESIGNATION><VALUE></VALUE></DESIGNATION><NATIONALITY><VALUE></VALUE></NATIONALITY><LIST_TYPE><VALUE></VALUE></LIST_TYPE><LAST_DAY_UPDATED><VALUE/></LAST_DAY_UPDATED><INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS><QUALITY></QUALITY><ALIAS_NAME></ALIAS_NAME></INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS><INDIVIDUAL_ADDRESS><COUNTRY/></INDIVIDUAL_ADDRESS><INDIVIDUAL_DATE_OF_BIRTH><TYPE_OF_DATE></TYPE_OF_DATE><DATE>1964-01-10</DATE></INDIVIDUAL_DATE_OF_BIRTH><INDIVIDUAL_PLACE_OF_BIRTH/><INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT/><SORT_KEY/><SORT_KEY_LAST_MOD/></INDIVIDUAL>
</INDIVIDUALS>
 <ENTITIES>
        <ENTITY><DATAID>1</DATAID><VERSIONNUM>1</VERSIONNUM><FIRST_NAME> TEST
</FIRST_NAME><SECOND_NAME>TEST SECOND
</SECOND_NAME><THIRD_NAME> TEST THIRD<THIRD_NAME></THIRD_NAME></THIRD_NAME><UN_LIST_TYPE></UN_LIST_TYPE><REFERENCE_NUMBER></REFERENCE_NUMBER><LISTED_ON>2012-09-11</LISTED_ON><COMMENTS1></COMMENTS1><LIST_TYPE><VALUE></VALUE></LIST_TYPE><LAST_DAY_UPDATED><VALUE/></LAST_DAY_UPDATED><ENTITY_ALIAS><QUALITY/><ALIAS_NAME/></ENTITY_ALIAS><ENTITY_ADDRESS><CITY></CITY><COUNTRY></COUNTRY></ENTITY_ADDRESS><SORT_KEY/><SORT_KEY_LAST_MOD/></ENTITY>
 <ENTITY><DATAID>2</DATAID><VERSIONNUM>1</VERSIONNUM><FIRST_NAME> TEST
</FIRST_NAME><SECOND_NAME>TEST SECOND
</SECOND_NAME><THIRD_NAME> TEST THIRD
<THIRD_NAME></THIRD_NAME></THIRD_NAME><UN_LIST_TYPE></UN_LIST_TYPE><REFERENCE_NUMBER></REFERENCE_NUMBER><LISTED_ON>2012-09-11</LISTED_ON><COMMENTS1></COMMENTS1><LIST_TYPE><VALUE></VALUE></LIST_TYPE><LAST_DAY_UPDATED><VALUE/></LAST_DAY_UPDATED><ENTITY_ALIAS><QUALITY/><ALIAS_NAME/></ENTITY_ALIAS><ENTITY_ADDRESS><CITY>Pyongyang</CITY><COUNTRY></COUNTRY></ENTITY_ADDRESS><SORT_KEY/><SORT_KEY_LAST_MOD/></ENTITY>
   </ENTITIES>
</CONSOLIDATED_LIST>
```

xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/CONSOLIDATED_LIST">
    <!-- INDIVIDUALS -->
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Individuals:&#10;DataID;First_Name;Second_Name;Third_Name&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="INDIVIDUALS/INDIVIDUAL">
        <xsl:value-of select="DATAID"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="FIRST_NAME"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="SECOND_NAME"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="THIRD_NAME" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- ENTITIES -->
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Entities:&#10;Dataid;First_Name;Second_Name&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="ENTITIES/ENTITY">
        <xsl:value-of select="DATAID"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="FIRST_NAME"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="SECOND_NAME" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
Individuals:
DataID;First_Name;Second_Name;Third_Name
5; TEST ;TEST1;
;TEST;TEST2;
Entities:
Dataid;First_Name;Second_name
1; TEST
;TEST SECOND

2; TEST
;TEST SECOND
```

Result expected:

```
Individuals:
DataID;First_Name;Second_Name;Third_Name
5; TEST ;TEST1;
;TEST;TEST2;
Entities:
Dataid;First_Name;Second_name
1; TEST;TEST SECOND
2; TEST;TEST SECOND
```

I was tried doing awk to the origin to remove all the newlines but I need to know how to do it in xslt parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of white space inside of element values you output with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="FIRST_NAME"/>` then using `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(FIRST_NAME)"/>` in XSLT 1 might help (but will also normalize sequence of spaces inside of text to one space).

Comment: a @Martin Honnen , many thanks for your comment and explanation of result, do you know where I can find some document of xsl design to view all this points detailed?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting newlines, because your **data** contains newlines. The contents of:

```
<SECOND_NAME>TEST SECOND
</SECOND_NAME>
```

is the text `"TEST SECOND&#10;"`.

If you want to remove the newlines, you can change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="SECOND_NAME" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(SECOND_NAME, '&#10;', '')" />
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(SECOND_NAME)" />
```

and likewise for any other field that may contain newlines. But be aware that this modifies the original data.

---

P.S. You may have a similar problem if the original field contains the `;` separator. Building a reliable CSV output is more complicated than this.